# Multiply each side of an inequality by a different amount

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

What are the rules for multiplying inequalities by unequal quantities please?

For example, by what property can we be certain that, given

$\frac{2}{10}<\frac{1}{2}$

it is true to say that

$\frac{1}{10}.\frac{2}{10}<\frac{1}{2}.\frac{1}{2}$

?

Comment: Is there a proof, or is it "just obvious" please? What about if one or both of the multipliers is negative?

Comment: Proof of this would use $x<y\implies f(x)<f(y)$ when $f$ is increasing. Here, for $0<a<b$ and $0<c<d$, we get $0<ac<bc$ (because, as $c>0$, the map $x\mapsto cx$ is increasing), and also $bc<bd$ (because $x\mapsto bx$ is increasing). Hence $0<ac<bd$. With negative slopes you need to pay more attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to look at this isn't as "one step" that multiplies each side by a different constant, but rather as a comparison of a series of inequalities such that you know one is bigger than the next is bigger than the next.

---

For example, lets say we're starting with the inequality:
$$
x < y
$$
and we want to know when the following inequality holds true,
$$
ax \stackrel{?}{<} by
$$
for any pair of constants $a$ and $b$. To make things easier for now, lets define $a\geq0$ and $a<b$ (we can look into more general cases later).

So, if we multiply both sides of the inequality by the first constant we have a new expression:
$$
ax < ay
$$
and from $a\geq0$ and $a<b$ we also know that the following expression must be true:
$$
ay < by
$$
which means that we know the following chain of inequalities holds true:
$$
ax < ay < by
$$
So, because we know that $by$ is larger than $ay$ is larger then $ax$... we know (for $a\geq0$ and $a<b$):
$$
ax < by
$$
Or, if we want to be slightly more concrete in terms of your example (where $x=2/10$ and $y=1/2$):
$$
\frac{1}{10} x < \frac{1}{2} y
$$

---

If you want to be more general with $a$ and $b$ such that $a>b$ or negative numbers are involved then the expressions above won't work anymore.  Mostly because they break the following steps:
$$
ax < ay
$$
Is false (for $x<y$) if $a<0$.  And:
$$
ay < by
$$
is false (for $x<y$) if $a>b$.

That isn't to say that we can't "chain inequalities" anymore... is just means that we have to chain a different set of expressions and that we have to be very careful with sign changes.

Comment: I think this is indeed the right way to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

One could make several rules that work of this kind. One rule, which your example is a case of:

> If $0<a<b$ and $0<c<d$ then $0<ac<bd.$

Can prove in two steps by first showing $ac<ad$ then showing $ad<bd$. both using usual rules.